# Iframe Navagation through textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

DON'T REPORT YET - READ FIRST
I'm trying to make a textbox and a button, then a iframe that whenever you press the button it goes to the URL in the textbox. I have tried:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
function navigate() {
$('#iframe1').attr('src', $('#ifrmsite').val());
return false;
}
</script></head>
<body>
Enter website url below:<br/>
    <form onSubmit="return navigate();" method="get" action="">
        <input type="text" value="http://www.w3schools.com/" name="ifrmSite" id="ifrmsite"/> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<br /><br />
    <iframe name="iframe1" id="iframe1" src="" width="600" height="700" scrolling="auto">
    </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

But... It doesn't work for me. You see, this script also changes the page url, and since I see this trough a iframe on my website, it just doesn't work. If anyone knows a way around this or a different way to do it, please tell me! :) have a nice day!

Comment: Some sites deny loading their site in iframe by using X-Frame-Options headers and other javascript blocking approaches. w3schools has such blocking and is why you don't see the iframe update. If you inspect the iframe in browser dev tools element inspector you will see your code does do the update of src

Comment: @charliefl I'm talking about my site... even the original html doc doesn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can, you have many pure js options:

```
var el = document.getElementById('ifrm');
el.src = url; // assign url to src property
```

```
window.frames['ifrm'].location = url;
//or
window.frames['ifrm'].location.replace(url);
```

if is your page you can just make links

```
<a href="page.html" target="_parent">link</a>
```

but remeber that will only work in the same origin.

"It is generally possible to load documents from other domains in iframes. However, it would not be possible for the containing document to make a reference to the document inside the iframe due to the restrictions of the Same Origin Policy. Also, the page from the other domain could contain code that would prevent its being loaded in your iframe."